# How do I exit a loop in C++ without using break?

Tags: c++, loops, break

I'm writing a code to swap integers in an array and I want to know how I can exit a loop without using a break statement and keeping my logic consistent. Here is my code below:

```
int swapped = 0;
if (arrays[0][first] % 2 == 0)
{
     cout << arrays[0][first] << " is odd " << endl;
     for (int i = 1; i < arraycount; ++i)
     {
         for (int j = 1; j < arrays[i][0] + 1; ++j)
         {
             if (arrays[i][j] % 2 != 0)
             {
                  int temp = arrays[i][j];
                  cout << "Array #" << 1 << " value " << arrays[0][first] << " swapped with "
                          << "Array #" << i << " value " << temp;

                  arrays[i][j] = arrays[0][first];
                  arrays[0][first] = temp;
                  swapped = 1;
                  break;
              }
          }
          if (swapped) {
                break;
          }
```

Comment: What's wrong with break?

Comment: This is C++. Why is `swapped` an `int`, when it works as a `bool`?

Comment: maybe `for ( initial; usual-condition && break-condition; stepper) {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Break statement does not necessarily make your codes logic inconsistent and breaks are often useful to improve the readability of your code. But in answer to your question this can be achieved by utilizing while loops and logical boolean operators. A modified version of your code is below, I have tried to modify it as little as possible so you can still see your code within the example. There are a few logical errors in your code that I have left in the example below that you might want to look into. In particular the line below will print "is odd" when in fact the number would be even. If you where wanting to check if the number `arrays[0][first]` is odd then the following if statement would be needed `if (arrays[0][first] % 2 != 0)` instead of `if (arrays[0][first] % 2 == 0)`.

**Logical Error**

```
if (arrays[0][first] % 2 == 0)
            {
                    cout << arrays[0][first] << " is odd " << endl;
```

**This is the code without using breaks.**

```
bool swapped = true;
            if (arrays[0][first] % 2 == 0)
            {
                    cout << arrays[0][first] << " is odd " << endl;
                    int i = 1;
                    while ( (i < arraycount) && swapped)
                    {
                            int j = 1;
                            bool if_odd = true;
                            while ((j < arrays[i][0] + 1) && if_odd)
                            {
                                    if (arrays[i][j] % 2 != 0)
                                    {
                                            int temp = arrays[i][j];
                                            cout << "Array #" << 1 << " value " << arrays[0][first] << " swapped with "
                                                    << "Array #" << i << " value " << temp;

                                            arrays[i][j] = arrays[0][first];
                                            arrays[0][first] = temp;
                                            swapped = false;
                                            if_odd = false;
                                    }
                                    j++;
                            }
                            i++;
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int i = 1; i < arraycount && !swapped; ++i)
{
     for (int j = 1; j < arrays[i][0] + 1 && !swapped; ++j)
     {
        if(arrays[i][j] % 2 != 0)
          int temp = arrays[i][j];
          cout << "Array #" << 1 << " value " << arrays[0][first] << " swapped with " << "Array #" << i << " value " << temp;
          arrays[i][j] = arrays[0][first];
          arrays[0][first] = temp;
          swapped = 1;
        }
     }
}
```

this will do the same thing you have in inner loop.

Comment: initially `int swapped = 0;`, so it will not enter first for loop.

Comment: in second loop, it want pass all the even numbers and for the first odd number `doSomethings`, then break. but in your code, it `doSometings` for all even numbers and when find first odd number, it returns from loop.

Comment: @alsa I value your comment greatly but I am not sure I understand what you are talking about?

Comment: OP's code and the code demonstrated here does not do the same thing, but the idea is applicable.

Comment: @GRC , in OP's code second loop is running until first `if (arrays[i][j] % 2 != 0)` condition occurs then its breaking the loop, but in you code it will skip the second loop if `arrays[i][j] % 2 != 0` condition is false. Plz correct that.

Comment: Sorry guys I see what you are talking about, my code would not execute a code inside a loop at all. Thank you :) It is late here and I had long day, do you guys mind if I fix this issue tmrw.

Answer (score 4):

Use goto [I'll be bashed because of this].

```
if (arrays[0][first] % 2 == 0)
{
     cout << arrays[0][first] << " is odd " << endl;
     for (int i = 1; i < arraycount; ++i)
     {
         for (int j = 1; j < arrays[i][0] + 1; ++j)
         {
             if (arrays[i][j] % 2 != 0)
             {
                  int temp = arrays[i][j];
                  cout << "Array #" << 1 << " value " 
                          << arrays[0][first] << " swapped with "
                          << "Array #" << i << " value " << temp;

                  arrays[i][j] = arrays[0][first];
                  arrays[0][first] = temp;
                  goto done;
              }
          }
done:
    something;
```

Comment: Multilevel breaks are, IMO, one of the main use cases for `goto` in modern C++.